# Upload problems with Candy-machine-v2/ problems with folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, candy-machine

it seems that i'm not able to perform the upload operation. I have tried to change from relative to absulute, but it keeps giving the same error. The -c flag(the directory with images + json) doesn't work.
Others flags work correctly.
What might be the problem?

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\nftmint\~> ts-node C:\Users\User\Documents\nftmint\~\~\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload     -e devnet     -k C:\Users\User\~\.config\solana     -cp config.json   -c example 
C:\Users\User\Documents\nftmint\~\~\metaplex\js\assets\images
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (node:fs:723:3)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:433:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:479:19)
    at loadWalletKey (C:\Users\User\Documents\nftmint\~\~\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\accounts.ts:571:34)
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\nftmint\~\~\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:84:40)
    at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (C:\Users\User\Documents\nftmint\~\~\metaplex\js\packages\cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:488:17)
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\nftmint\~\~\metaplex\js\packages\cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1227:65
    at Command._chainOrCall (C:\Users\User\Documents\nftmint\~\~\metaplex\js\packages\cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1144:12)
    at Command._parseCommand (C:\Users\User\Documents\nftmint\~\~\metaplex\js\packages\cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1227:27)
    at Command._dispatchSubcommand (C:\Users\User\Documents\nftmint\~\~\metaplex\js\packages\cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1050:25) {
  errno: -4068,
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'EISDIR'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As referenced from the metaplex docs here: https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/creating-candy-machine

-c is NOT the directory containing images+json pairs. This is an **optional** flag that specifies the location of the .cache file. Not necessary as the .cache file won't be created until you run the upload cmd.

In saying the above things the cmd you would probably want to run is:

`ts-node C:\Users\User\Documents\nftmint\~\~\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e devnet -k C:\Users\User\~\.config\solana.json     -cp config.json ./assets` where the assets folder contains your image and json pairs named from 0.png and 0.json through to n.png and n.json.